# Does Lyft limits requests to their API for whole app?

Tags: rate-limiting, lyft-api

There's an information in Lyft docs (https://developer.lyft.com/docs/rate-limits) that "Rate limits are global and are enforced on a per-client ID basis.". Is that really true? Lyft limits all requests based on client-id? For example POST to the Ride-Request is limited for 5 rq per minute - that works for one user or for whole app (since we're using client-id)? It doesn't make sense if all requests are limited for whole app.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Lyft API, but in general, when an API who uses OAuth says it is enforcing rate limiting on **client ID**, that means your whole app, not a specific user.

For example, let's say you have an app with two users: user `a` and `b`. User `a` does two requests and `b` does another two. That means your client ID just did **four** requests and you have only **one** request left.

You can check if that is true creating two different users in your app, doing requests and checking the `X-Ratelimit-Remaining` header after the request